# child_process and moongose. Execute script asynchronously and use result in model.create

Tags: python, json, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I want to execute a python script that performs an ETL process and returns a JSON object that is going to be used to create a document (an instance of my mongoose model) and store it in MongoDB. I am running the script correctly with the help of the node.js library `child_process`, but the document is created before the child process has been finished. How must I modify my code to execute the python script asynchronously (without blocking the Node.js event loop) and use the result to create a document of my mongoose model?

```
// Creates a new Report in the DB (report controller)
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
export function create(req, res) {

    var json_report = "";
    var path2file = path.join(__dirname, "/../../../python_reporter/reports/", "node_connector.py");
    var python = spawn('python', [path2file]);
    var request_body = {};

    //We are going to receive a JSON-like string from python 
    python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        json_report += data.toString();
    });

    python.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    python.stdout.on('exit', function () {
        json_report = JSON.parse(json_report);
        for(var key in req.body){
            request_body[String(key)] = req.body[key];
        }
        for(var key in json_report){
            request_body[String(key)] = json_report[key];
        }
        console.log(request_body)
        console.log("JSON object successfully created");
    });

    return Report.create(request_body)
        .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
        .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a return statement, you just put it inside your 'exit' block.

```
python.stdout.on('exit', function () {
    json_report = JSON.parse(json_report);
    for(var key in req.body){
        request_body[String(key)] = req.body[key];
    }
    for(var key in json_report){
        request_body[String(key)] = json_report[key];
    }
    console.log(request_body)
    console.log("JSON object successfully created");

    Report.create(request_body)
      .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
      .catch(handleError(res));

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped!